# How to write a slice into a file?

Tags: rust

I have code which interracts with C via bindings. In it I have this:

```
let a1: *const i8 = get_data();
let size1 = get_size_of_data();

let a2 = ::std::slice::from_raw_parts(a2, size1);
```

I need to write data to which `a1` points. Or `a2` as a slice. The size or length of the data is known.

I tried:

```
  let mut f1 = File::create("my_file.dat").unwrap();
  // ??? f1.write_all(a2).expect("unable to write binary data to file");
  // ??? f1.write_all(a2.as_bytes).expect("unable to write binary data to file");
```

and nothing has compiled.

How to do it?

Comment: Apart from @nullptr's answer, it should also be noted that your `::std::slice::from_raw_parts(a2, size1)`, contained a2, and should be a1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need pass a `&[u8]` to `write_all`, but you have a `&[i8]`. So, the only change you need is to cast your `*const i8` to a `*const u8` in `slice::from_raw_parts`

```
let a1: *const i8 = std::ptr::null(); // replace with `get_data()`
let size1 = 42; // replace `get_size_of_data()`

let a2: &[u8] = unsafe { std::slice::from_raw_parts(a1 as *const u8, size1) };

use std::io::Write;
let mut f1 = std::fs::File::create("my_file.dat").unwrap();
f1.write_all(a2).expect("write must succeed");
```

Comment: But if `a1` contains negative values, how would it be casted to `u8`?

Comment: `write_all` writes **bytes**. It doesn't attempt to interpret the bytes it writes.

Comment: @mixtouku When you cast a `*const i8` to a `*const u8` if the value pointed to is negative, say `-5` (i.e. the byte `11111011`) `*const u8` will simply read the value as a positive value (here 251). i.e. the bits are not changed, it is still represented as  `11111011`. So, you can safely cast between `*const i8` and `*const u8` and write the `&[u8]` here.

Comment: Is that proper  casting?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by proper? It is a safe cast, and makes sense in this context.

Comment: I can't explain